# How can I refresh the plugins cache manually?

Tags: plugins, cache

I'm installing a plugin **by code via an AJAX call** and afterwards, I'm using `get_plugins` to retrieve the new list of plugins.

Problem is, my list is still the old one, where there's no plugins that are to be activated, it just sits empty, but if I refresh the page and dump my plugin list, it's there, ready to be activated which shows this is a caching issue.

Using `wp_clean_plugins_cache` has absolutely no effect.

Comment: when do you read the list of plugin ? in the code that activated the plugin or in another AJAX call ?

Comment: @Kaperto I'm reading the plugin list exactly when WP loads. I'm using TGMPA to get the list, then, with my own functions, I activate plugins from there **with an AJAX call**, after this call, I expect that I'll be able to see a newly updated TGMPA array, or at least something. One interesting thing is if I click on the "install" button twice, it works, as in, the list actually does update.

Comment: @Kaperto I...I did it. I put an AJAX call inside an AJAX call and it works. But this is dirty. Is there just no way to clear cache after a function call, so that the next function sees the updated data?